# HTML5; validating for only letters A-K and numbers, length 3

Tags: html, regex

I'm creating a user form, where I only want them to enter their Seats - but I only want them to enter letters A-K and numbers 0-9; e.g they could input A20, but they cannot input L45 or AL. They can also enter comma separated values e.g A20, B3 if they wanted to.

Here's what I got so far, but I haven't had any luck:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Seats (uppercase letters only)<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="seats" class="form-control" pattern="^[A-k0-9{0,3}]+(, [A-k0-9]{0,3}+)*$" title="That seat doesn't exist. Please try again." required >
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you're after a regular expression to validate airplane seating?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make it clear before in my original post.

Comment: Case should not be a criteria. Simply change any entered text to fit upper or lower case. Case conformity is a fail/fail coding criteria -- you're making it harder for the user with absolutely no benefit for the system.

Comment: `^([a-kA-K])([0-9]{1,2})$` https://regex101.com/r/mJbL3h/1

Comment: @melancia this doesn't take account of the multiple values that might appear as described by the OP.

Comment: what about this one: `^[A-K][0-9][0-9]?(,\s*[A-K][0-9][0-9]?)*$`

Comment: Would the value `AB4` be valid? Woudl the value `A1` be value? Or is it always `<letter><number><number>`. Pleaser clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Validating for only letters A-K and numbers, length 3

Standard PCRE can be used to produce this:

```
/^([a-k0-9]{3}[,\h]*)*$/ig
```

## UPDATE:

HTML Pattern uses Javascript regex so the following can work in that syntax:

```
 /^([a-k0-9]{3}[,\s]*)*$/ig
```

## How this works:

- Match a single character present in the list  `[a-k0-9]`:
- `{3}` matches the previous token (`[a-k0-9]`) exactly 3 times
- `a-k` matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and k  - (index 107) (case insensitive)
- `0-9` matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57)
- Match a single character present in the list  `[,\s]`
- `*` matches the previous token (`[,\s]`) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `,` matches the character , literally (case insensitive)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `$` matches the end of the string input
  **Global pattern flags**
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

## Matches:

> ```
> A23 BB4
> ```

> ```
> A23, BB4
> ```

> ```
> A23 BB4 CD4
> ```

## Non Matches:

> ```
> A235 BB4 CD4, LL46
> ```

## Note about Case Sensitivity

Case of letters should not be a factor in deciding if a code is valid. The case can be easily converted on any server side processing you do (or even with Javascript to upper-case or lower-case any input as it happens.

People using the system with mobile devices will often have case set by the mobile keyboard, as in first letter is upper, following letters are lower, etc. and this can cause false failures for your Regex Pattern.

Here you're making it harder for the user with absolutely no benefit for the system as the system can trivially transition to a uniform case at any later point, as mentioned.